# How to add different string lines to a new column and each row in a csv?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, logging

[Image of the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v4UX.png)
i want to get the "Messages:" (in the Generals tab) line to the "CCIS_Error_Log_2017-05-03.csv" in a new column each row mapping the corresponding event.

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{logname = 'CCIS'; } | where {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq "Error"}|select Message)|Set-Content -Path "C:\Logs\temp.txt"

Import-Csv C:\CCIS_Error_Log_2017-05-03.csv|select-object *,@{Name="Messages";Expression={select-string C:\Logs\temp.txt -pattern "Message:" | foreach {$_.Line}}} | Export-Csv C:\Logs\CCIS_Error_Log_2017-05-03.csv -notypeinformation
```

This is a segment of the script i wrote to do the above scenario. but instead mapping to the event it copies all the "Messages:" in each event to a single row in the csv file.

I hope i explained it well
Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way can you map the lines in the CSV file to the events in the event log? E.g do they have the same timestamp or any other ID key? A few sample entries from the CSV file might help.

Comment: "Id,TimeCreated,LevelDisplayName,ProviderName" These are the column names

Comment: OK so you could use TimeCreated but only if the timestamps are in the same format and match exactly. Are the events in the CSV from the event log or another source?

Comment: from the event log, but is it possible to use the event id instead?

Comment: Yep, i've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible to map the Events to the entries in the Error CSV file exactly by Timestamp then this could be a solution (assumes that there is a Timestamp column in the CSV):

```
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{logname = 'CCIS'} | Where {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq "Error"}
$ErrorLog = Import-Csv C:\CCIS_Error_Log_2017-05-03.csv 

$ErrorLog | ForEach-Object {

    $LogEntry = $_
    $Event = $Events | Where {$_.Id -eq $LogEntry.Id}

    If ($Event){
        Write-Output ($LogEntry | Select *,@{Name='Message';Expression={$Event.Message}})
    }Else{
        Write-Warning "Could not locate a matching message for $LogEntry"
    }

} | Export-CSV C:\Logs\CCIS_Error_Log_2017-05-03.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: the issue is 'id' nor the 'timestamp' (server time is local time while the application time is in a different time zone) is unique therefore i cannot map the query.

Comment: is there another way i can do this 
i've attached a screen shot 
http://imgur.com/a/tM5jZ